# Best resources for learning Play! Framework

Tags: java, books, playframework

Awhile back I [discussed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74524/net-guy-offered-a-java-job) the possibility of moving to a startup that is going to be using Java, more specifically the Play! Framework; well, I'm going to go for it! I have been a .NET guy for a long time now and haven't really been in the Java game except for the occasional Android tinkering or messing around with Scala a little bit. I have looked at the Play! Framework before but only on a cursory level. I think I will be fine with Java as a language, as I've been [given great advice before on learning materials](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51115/best-java-books-for-an-experienced-developer).

My question, is aside from the very great site for the Play! Framework I haven't found much else out there except a few blogs. Does anyone know of any other good resources for the Play! Framework like books? An Amazon search turned up zero results.

I know there is an eBook floating around out there but it seems a little outdated at this point. Anyway, thanks for your input.

Comment: I dabbled with Play! before switching to Grails. I would take a close look at Grails for comparison.

Comment: Funny, I was wondering earlier (as it looks increasingly certain I'll be taking the opportunity I mentioned) what you'd decided to do in the end. Good luck, sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [standard documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/home) covers the framework brilliantly.

Additionally you can take a look at the [play book](http://www.the-play-book.co.uk/) and there is a [developer blog](http://playframework.blogspot.com/) if you are interested.

It's an awesome framework and I've tried most of other Java framework before I settled with Play!. There is an excellent "hidden" productivity booster in the framework. Leaving it to you to find it out :-).

Comment: Thanks for the info! Hidden productivity booster eh, I plan on spending the day learning as much as possible about it.

Answer (score 1):

[Introduction to Play! Framework](http://www.the-play-book.co.uk/) is an excellent introduction to Play.

In the recent days [Play Framework Cookbook](http://www.packtpub.com/play-framework-cookbook/book) appeared that cover the framework in much detail. With this book, and willing to have a look at Play's code (it's really easy to follow!) you'll be able to move with Play! at ease.

Also you should sign in [Play Framework Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework) and follow [Play Framework Knowledge Base](http://www.the-play-book.co.uk/) for news and articles.